# Cordova html5 Audio stream stops after some minutes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, html5-audio

I've created a Vue, Cordova app and we want to implement a radio stream into the app. When a user clicks play the app starts a livestream via an URL. Problem is, when the user puts the app to the background OR when the phone goes into sleep mode the streams stops after approx 15 minutes. I think IOS and Android snooze the app (disconnect it from the network).

After some searching ive found a cordova library which should prevent this but the library does not work.

- vue@2.6.11
- cordova@10.0.0

> Installed platforms:

- android 8.0.0
- ios 5.1.1

My config.xml:

```xml
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="3.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.6.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="0.7.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode-fixed" spec="0.7.8" />
```

my index.html:

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
}
```

My App.vue:

```html
<audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
    <source src='https://media1.hostin.cc/punt24.mp3' type='audio/wav' />
</audio>
<v-btn v-bind:class="{'d-none': this.$root.playStream}" icon x-large @click="playStream" v-bind:updaterplay="updaterPlay">
    <v-icon>$vuetify.icons.playbutton</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<v-btn v-bind:class="{'d-none': !this.$root.playStream}" icon x-large @click="playStream" v-bind:updaterplay="updaterPlay">
    <v-icon>$vuetify.icons.stopbutton</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

```js
playStream(){
    var method = 'pause';
    var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio');
    if(this.$root.playStream){
        this.$root.playStream = false;
        method = 'pause';
    }else{
        this.$root.playStream = true;
        method = 'play';
    }
    yourAudio[method]();
    this.updaterPlay++;
},
```

Anyone any idea's?